# How to use Html.DropDownListFor in another

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Question about @Html.DropDownListFor

I have 2 class :

```
Public Class A01WorkRecord
Public Property counter As Int32
Public Property MembetNumber As Int16
Public Property Memo As String
Public Property WorkDate As Date
End Class

Public Class B01Member
Public Property counter As Int32
Public Property Number As Int16
Public Property Name As Date
End Class
```

the VIEW is for create Work Record
so I want the view can chooise Member Name and write work memo

so in the Controller

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim q = From p In db.B01s
            Select p.Number, p.Name

    Dim ListItem As List(Of SelectListItem) = New List(Of SelectListItem)
    For Each l In q
        ListItem.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Text = l.Name, .Value = l.Number})
    Next
    ViewData("List") = New SelectList(ListItem, "Value", "Text", "")

    Return View()
End Function
```

and in the View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.MembetNumber ,ViewData("Item"))
```

I want to choose name, but it's not working ...

the error message:

> No Type is 'IEnumerable' and index 'Number' ViewData Item

I don't Know what's Wrong, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example provided it appears that you are might be mixing up `ViewData("Item")` with `ViewData("List")`

So try this instead

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.MembetNumber, ViewData("List"))
```